# png to bmp conversion (maintaining transparency)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am using delphi XE-5 and I am loading button information from a JSON file, in order to create buttons on a TMS ADVToolBar control. Each button is 50X35 and in png format with transparency.

I am getting each url, using the idHTTP component to retrieve it to a stream and then load it into a png. I then draw it onto a transparent BMP. However, I dont think this is the correct way. Anyway, the bmp is then added to a TImageList where it is assigned to a button using the index.  The Image shows up on the button, but with no transparency.

see my code below:

```
 imgUrl:= //code to get img url from JSON file;

 MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
 png := TPngImage.Create;
 png.Transparent:= True;
 try
  idHTTP1.get(imgUrl,MS);
  Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
  png.LoadFromStream(MS);
  bmp:= TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.Transparent:= True;
  bmp.Width:= 50;
  bmp.Height:= 50;
  png.Draw(bmp.Canvas, Rect(7, 7, png.Width, png.Height));
  ImageList1.Add(bmp, nil);
  AdvGlowBtn.Images:= ImageList1;
  AdvGlowBtn.Layout:= blGlyphTop;
  AdvGlowBtn.WordWrap:= False;
  AdvGlowBtn.AutoSize:= True;

  AdvGlowBtn.ImageIndex:= ImageList1.Count-1;

  bmp.Free;
 finally
 FreeAndNil(png);
 FreeAndNil(MS);
 end;
```

Comment: You presumably don't want `Transparent`. You presumably want a 32bpp bitmap.

Comment: Why you don't use PNG directly instead of converting it to BMP?

Comment: Try GraphicEx or Vampyre Imaging ... but best of all just use PNGs directly

Comment: @Arioch, it's as easy [`as this`](http://pastebin.com/C6sBUVFw) without 3rd party... But add directly PNGs is the best bet.

Comment: @TLama - is this true? A TImageList's glyph size has to be proportional, do they not. (ex. 50X50) In this case, the Images coming from the internet are 50X35. I get Invalid Image Size errors.

Comment: @LuvRAD, the `Assign` method takes also size of the source graphics. Well, that size difference is very important "detail" (I took the size you mentioned as a typo comparing to your code). So you actually want to crop or stretch them keeping transparency...

Comment: @ Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira - because I am trying to deal with the 50X35 image size issue. How do I get them into a TIMageList and use them by their index property without throwing a Invalid Image error

Comment: @TLama  - what about the TImaeList. Howdo you put a 50X35 into a TIMageList that needs to be 50X50?

Comment: @ Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira - using PNG directly creates a [dcc32 Error] UntMain.pas(117): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBitmap' and 'TPngImage'   error when adding png to TImageList

Comment: @TLama - "But add directly PNGs is the best bet"  - how do I add a PNG directly to a TImageList?

Comment: @LuvRAD, sorry. That's a typo. I wanted to say "use" instead of "add". Btw. could you elaborate on what is your aim, please ? It's somehow hidden that you want to resize it keeping transparency before adding to the image list. Except that we need to know if you want to crop it or stretch into the target size.

Comment: My aim is to just take images that already reside on the internet (on our host site) and place them on buttons. I am essentially creating a TRibbon control (really its the TMS software version though ) at runtime, all its tabs, groups, and buttons come from a JSON File. The url to each button glyph resides in this JSON file as well. Unfortunately, all the images are 50X35. I need to place these glyphs on the buttons as transparent. I have no problem getting the images on the buttons, unfortunatley, they all have white backgrounds. However, they are transparent on the internet as pngs

Comment: So, i guess that means I need to stretch the png? I dont know? Can a TImageList take a 50X35 size image? Cause I keep getting invalid Image size errros if its not propertional

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46168/discussion-between-luvrad-and-tlama)

Answer (score 3):

At first you have to **enable** the **runtime themes** (Project Manager) otherwise you will have **no transparency** of your images.

And this is the code to load the PNG image into your `ImageList1`

```
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  // everything done before to bmp has no effect
  bmp.Assign( png );
  // if for some reason the loaded image is smaller
  // set the size to avoid the invalid image size error
  bmp.Width := ImageList1.Width;
  bmp.Height := ImageList1.Height;

  AdvGlowBtn.Images:= ImageList1;
  ...
  // now add the Bitmap to the ImageList
  AdvGlowBtn.ImageIndex := ImageList1.Add( bmp, nil );
finally
  bmp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This is most likely a good solution, but does not work for me since I failed to mention that my png images are of various sizes (largest being 50X35)

Comment: Sorry, but I can only answer the questions asked. Now you know how to convert from PNG to Bitmap without loosing the transparency. If you have another question then you should ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

I have an old project in Delphi 5 and I still using it sometimes.
This is my solution using the png object.

```
procedure ImageList2Alpha(const ImageList: TImageList);
const
  Mask: array[Boolean] of Longint = (0, ILC_MASK);
var
  TempList: TImageList;
begin
  if Assigned(ImageList) then
  begin
    TempList := TImageList.Create(nil);
    try
      TempList.Assign(ImageList);
      with ImageList do
      begin
        Handle := ImageList_Create(Width, Height, ILC_COLOR32 or Mask[Masked], 0, AllocBy);
        if not HandleAllocated then
          raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SInvalidImageList);
      end;
      Imagelist.AddImages(TempList);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(TempList);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure LoadPngToBmp(var Dest: TBitmap; AFilename: TFilename);
type 
  TRGB32 = packed record 
    B, G, R, A : Byte;
  end; 
  PRGBArray32 = ^TRGBArray32; 
  TRGBArray32 = array[0..0] of TRGB32;
type
  TRG24 = packed record
    rgbtBlue, rgbtGreen, rgbtRed : Byte;
  end;
  PRGBArray24 = ^TPRGBArray24;
  TPRGBArray24 = array[0..0] of TRG24;
type
  TByteArray = Array[Word] of Byte;
  PByteArray = ^TByteArray;
  TPByteArray = array[0..0] of TByteArray;
var
  BMP : TBitmap;
  PNG: TPNGObject;
  x, y: Integer; 
  BmpRow: PRGBArray32;
  PngRow : PRGBArray24;
  AlphaRow: PByteArray;
begin

  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  PNG := TPNGObject.Create;

  try

    if AFilename <> '' then
    begin

      PNG.LoadFromFile(AFilename);
      BMP.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      BMP.Height := PNG.Height;
      BMP.Width := PNG.Width;

      if ( PNG.TransparencyMode = ptmPartial ) then
      begin

        for Y := 0 to BMP.Height-1 do
        begin

          BmpRow := PRGBArray32(BMP.ScanLine[Y]);
          PngRow := PRGBArray24(PNG.ScanLine[Y]);
          AlphaRow := PByteArray(PNG.AlphaScanline[Y]);

          for X := 0 to BMP.Width - 1 do
          begin
            with BmpRow[X] do
            begin
              with PngRow[X] do
              begin
                R := rgbtRed; G := rgbtGreen; B := rgbtBlue;
              end;
              A := Byte(AlphaRow[X]);
            end;
          end;

        end;

      end else
      begin

        for Y := 0 to BMP.Height-1 do
        begin

          BmpRow := PRGBArray32(BMP.ScanLine[Y]);
          PngRow := PRGBArray24(PNG.ScanLine[Y]);

          for X := 0 to BMP.Width - 1 do
          begin
            with BmpRow[X] do
            begin
              with PngRow[X] do
              begin
                R := rgbtRed; G := rgbtGreen; B := rgbtBlue;
              end;
              A := 255;
            end;
          end;

        end;

      end;

      Dest.Assign(BMP);

    end;

  finally
    Bmp.Free;
    PNG.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Call ImageList2Alpha(YourImageList) on the OnCreate of the Form (FormCreate), and the ImageList will be ready to store your Bitmaps32 keeping the transparency.

Call the LoadPngToBmp procedure to convert a PNG to Bitmap32 and then, store it on your ImageList.

Comment: It works. :) And to compile, added these units at uses section: Winapi.CommCtrl, Vcl.Consts.

Comment: I have no idea why my XE5 shows runtime error at `A := Byte(AlphaRow[X]);` when I try to load a faulty png file that doesn't go properly into an IL at designtime (shows blank or black).

Answer (score 1):

The `TBitmap` class uses Windows own libraries to manipulate Bitmaps. Depending on you Windows version, the underlying Operating System libraries does not support 32 bits BMPs, despite the libraries header files declares a `BITMAPQUAD` struct.

For newer versions of Windows (Vista and above afaik), the field `BITMAPQUAD.reserved` is used to store the alpha channel. For older versions, this field must remain zero (0x00).

If you are using a "recent" version of Windows, the only possible explanation I see is that the `TBitmap` class were not updated to support the alpha channel.

Using the class `TPNGImage` should not be an issue instead of converting it to BMP before using, unless you have some more specific needs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that XP supports alpha in bitmaps. And didn't win2k.

Comment: the more specific needs are laid out in the initial post. How to get a 50X35 png into a ImageList and maintain its transparency, so i can place them on a button

Comment: @LuvRAD The docs state that it is supported, but as you noticed, there is no way to add a `TPNGImage` directly into a `TImageList`. I find this lack of documentation disturbing. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Controls.TImageList

Answer (score 1):

Use it like that:

```
ABitmap.SetSize(png.Width, png.Height);
png.AssignTo(ABitmap);
```